# xamarin forms binding nested Lists in ListView in code behind

Tags: data-binding, xamarin.forms, nested-lists

I am trying to bind Foo to this listview. I have attempted to use custom converters and i have attempted to use nested listviews. Should this been done in the code behind? What is the best way of accomplishing this task?

```
<ListView x:Name="DisplayFoos">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
        <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Spacing="0" Margin="0">
                    <customControl:CustomFrame CornerRadius="2" BackgroundColor="White" OutlineColor="Gray" Margin="0">
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                            <Label FontSize="Large" Text="{Binding FooDate,StringFormat='{0:M/dd/yyyy}'}" TextColor="White" />
                            <Label FontSize="Large" Text="{Binding NumberOfBars,StringFormat='{0} Vehicles'}"  TextColor="White" />
                        </StackLayout> 
                    </customControl:CustomFrame>
                    <Frame CornerRadius="2" BackgroundColor="White" OutlineColor="Gray" Margin="0">
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"  VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="White" Margin="5,5,5,5">
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                            <Image Source="{Binding PropOne}" HeightRequest="80" WidthRequest="80" Aspect="AspectFill" />
                        </StackLayout>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" >
                                        <Label Margin="16,0,0,0"  Text="{Binding PropTwo}" FontSize="Micro" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="Black"  />
                                    <Label  Text="{Binding PropThree}" FontSize="Micro" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="Black"  />
                                        <Label  Text="{Binding PropFour}" FontSize="Micro" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="Black"   />
                                        <Label  Text="{Binding PropFive}" FontSize="Micro" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="Black"  />
                                    <Label  Text=" - " FontSize="Small" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="Black"   />
                                    <Label  Text="{Binding PropSix}" FontSize="Micro" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="Black"   />
                                </StackLayout>
                                <Label Margin="5,0,0,0"  Text="Some Text"  FontSize="Small" HorizontalOptions="Start" TextColor="Red"  IsVisible="{Binding PropSeven}"/>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </StackLayout>
                </Frame>
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

> ```
> public class Foo
> {
>   public DateTime FooDate {get; set; }
>   public int NumberOfBars {get; set; }
>   public List<Bar> ListOfBars { get; set; }
>
> }
> public class Bar
> {
>   string PropOne {get set;}
>   string PropTwo {get; set;}
>   string PropThree {get; set;}
>   string PropFour {get; set;}
>   string PropFive {get; set; }
>   string PropSix  {get; set; }
>   bool PropSeven {get; set; }
> }
> ```

```
ObservableCollectiont<Foo> listOfFoos = new ObservableCollection<Foo>();
DisplayFoos.ItemSource = listOfFoos;
```

Comment: generally you would have a 2nd page with another listview - selecting an item of the first page would then display the 2nd page with the detail listing for that item.

Comment: i get that Jason and you are probably but as of now, it is a require for the UI per se...should i make a class just for displaying this data?

Comment: you can just add a read only property that will return your ListOfBars as a single string which you can bind to a label

Comment: The problem with that approach is the label are separated...Sorry for the confusion i caused. I have now update the question with the exact view that i am using. The only different is the names of the properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a converter.

```
public class ListToStringConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is IList<Bar> list)
        {
            return string.Join(", ", list.Select(x => x.PropertyB));
        }
        return null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
<DataTemplate>
    <ViewCell>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="{Binding PropertyA}" />
            <Label Text="{Binding ListOfBars, 
                            Converter={StaticResource ListToStringConverter}}" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ViewCell>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: this is very close to what i am looking for. But this returns a list...My "ListOfBars" in reality is a complex object. It there a way to convert one item at a time instead of receiving a list?

Comment: (the titles are in "Foo", But the actual properties are in "Bar")

Comment: When you mention the `Bar` is a complex object - how complex is the view that's supposed to be rendered?

Comment: Bar has six strings and a bool

Comment: Ok - I will look into this and get back to you. Give me sometime.

Comment: In the meantime - I would recommend to try and [explore the grouping logic](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/UserInterface/ListView/Grouping/) to have nested like lists (you can HeaderTemplate for `Foo`, and ItemTemplate for `Bar`